# knife from within a Makefile (chef)

Tags: makefile, chef-infra, gnu-make

I have a chef workstation setup and working correctly.  I would like to use Makefile to wrap some knife commands.  For instance I made:

```
# Simple Makefile
.PHONY: upload_roles nodes
upload_roles:
    knife upload /roles

nodes:
    knife list nodes
```

Then I get these errors:

```
$ make upload_roles
knife upload /roles
WARNING: No knife configuration file found

$ make nodes
knife list nodes
WARNING: No knife configuration file found
ERROR: Attempt to use relative path 'nodes' when current directory is outside the repository path.
ERROR: Current working directory is '/home/x/work/chef'.
Makefile:23: recipe for target 'nodes' failed
make: *** [nodes] Error 1
```

However if I just run the commands I get the correct results:

```
$ knife upload /roles
Updated roles/dev_samba.json
```

What am I missing? How can I figure out what env I am missing or something else?

Comment: Do you run the command in that same directory, `/home/x/work/chef`?

Comment: yeah it's always in the same directory

Comment: Notice that make is using `sh` not `bash`, so it might be that the shell call `knife list nodes` is ignorant of some of the default variables (in `.bashrc` ?) .

Comment: [vroomfondel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1819452/vroomfondel) is very likely right: the shell you're using on the command line and the shell used by make to execute the recipes are probably different. And this difference probably explains the different behaviors. If your command-line shell is `bash`, try to add `SHELL := bash` as the first line of your Makefile and see if it solves the problem. Then, if you really want to use the default shell in your Makefile, find out what configuration it needs in order to run your commands without errors.

Comment: Adding `SHELL := bash` works for me.  If you convert your comment to an answer I will accept

Comment: Comments cannot be converted into answers. Either reply to @Renaud and ask him to post an answer, or post an answer of your own, giving him the credit for the solution.

Comment: @portforwardpodcast: Glad you solved your problem. I posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by [vroomfondel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1819452/vroomfondel) the shell you're using on the command line and the shell used by `make` to execute the recipes are probably different. And this difference probably explains the different behaviors. If your command-line shell is `bash`, try to add:

```
SHELL := bash
```

as the first line of your Makefile and see if it solves the problem. Then, if you really want to use the default shell in your makefile, find out what configuration it needs in order to run your commands without errors.